# How to get a collection of lists to a list using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have a list

```
List<List<Employee>> EmployeeListCollection;
```

and want to

```
List<Employee> EmployeeList=//all employee in EmployeeListCollection
```

what's the query?

Comment: Your question is to vague, can you explain what you need???

Comment: sorry,i'm really bad in english,so i usually try to give sample when i have question,and i think this sample is clear,and as you see the others understand what i mean!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
List<Employee> EmployeeList = EmployeeListCollection.SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<List<Employee>> EmployeeListCollection;
List<Employee> EmployeeList;
foreach(var emplst in EmployeeListCollection)
{
  foreach(var emp in emplst )
 {
     EmployeeList.add(emp);
 }
}
```